# MAX20077 buck converter issue

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply, buck

I'm using MAX20077ATCB_VY+ voltage regulator. Trying to get +5 V out of it. Power supply is 12 V. EN pin is +12 V and SPS is connected to GND and as SYNC pin is not connected it should work in SKIP mode. Issue is that it's outputting like 1.90 Hz not 400 kHz as it supposed to and nowhere near 5 V.

I did try to attach FB to BIAS, to get 3.3 V, no luck either, signal looked pretty much the same. OUT5 from resistor network is connected after inductor on pcb. Tried many ICs and same result, so don't think IC`s are bad.

What could be the issue?

This is my schematic:

[image]

This is output power signal from scope (12 V is stable):

[image]

Comment: Can you provide links to the datasheets of the inductor and the input and output capacitors?